# ImportError: No module named not_found

Tags: python, google-app-engine

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import google
print google.__path__.append("C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\google_appengine")
import webapp2
form ="""
<form method ="post" action= "/testform">
<input name="q">
<input type="submit">
</form>    
"""
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content­Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write(form)
class TestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        q = self.request.get("q")
        self.response.out.write(q)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('/', MainPage),
('/testform',TestHandler),
], debug=True)
```

when i run this simple app it show the text-area and the submit but when i submit i get 500 error. and on the power shell i get the following:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
obj = __import__(path[0])
ImportError: No module named not_found
INFO     2017-01-14 21:16:13,831 module.py:806] default: "POST /testform HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: How are you running the app?  Using dev_appserver.py?  Try deleting the first two lines because they don't look necessary.

Comment: yes I am running the app using dev_appserver.py ...even after deleting the first two lines I get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you use **app.yaml** that is an example [in Google AppEngine Docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref) .

If you delete below two linse from app.yaml, you can fix.

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  script: home.app

- url: /index\.html
  script: home.app

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

 - url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))$
   static_files: static/\1
   upload: static/.*\.(gif|png|jpg)$

- url: /admin/.*
  script: admin.app
  login: admin

- url: /.*              // <- delete this
  script: not_found.app // <- delete this
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some indentation errors in your code, and you need a `post` method for the form response.  See below for fixed code.

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content­Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write(form)

class TestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        q = self.request.get("q")
        self.response.out.write(q)
```

I'm not sure that this will fix all your problems, but it will at least get you closer.

Comment: this didn't solve the problem buddy .... would you suggest something else.

Comment: Update your question and show what happens after you have applied the fix in my answer.

Comment: after i've applied your fix but it shows the same error.